# i need to know how compiler work with destructors in cpp

Tags: c++

Lets say I have 2 diffrent classes.

Why when I put class `A` object as data member inside class `B`, the class that getting destroyed first is class `B` and then class A but when i put class `A` object in the builder of class `B` then class `A` getting destroyed first and then class `B`? for example:

```
class A {
public:
    ~A() { std::cout << "Deleting A\n"; }
};

class B {
private:
    A object;
public:
    ~B() { std::cout << "Deleting B\n"; }
};

int main( void ) {
    B test;
    return 0;
}
```

result:

> Deleting B
>   Deleting A

But the next example gives me the opposite result :

```
class A {
public:
    ~A() { std::cout << "Deleting A\n"; }
};

class B {
public:
    B() { A object; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "Deleting B\n"; }
};

int main( void ) {
    B test;
    return 0;
}
```

result:

> Deleting A
>   Deleting B

Comment: In the second case, the A is a local variable, not a member.

Comment: Ask yourself: when does a object local to a function get destroyed?

Comment: In the second case, the object A is destroyed at the end of the B constructor, when it goes out of scope. Debug it step by step putting a breakpoint in your destructors... you'll see it ;)

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#order-dtors-for-members

Comment: Refer to this [destruction sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Destruction_sequence) reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example `B test;` calls the constructor of B.

The constructor B is just a function and it has a local variable `A object;`. This object is created and at the end of the scope (end of the constructor of B) it is detroyed.

Back in main at the end of main the object `test` is destroyed.

So in that case the object `A object;` is destroyed first, later object `B test;` is destroyed.

In your first example this is something different. There `A object;` is a member of class B, so the constructor of B is constructing the member automatically. The order of construction is: base classes first (not present in your example), then members, then the body of the constructor. Destruction is the opposite order: body of the destructor first, then the members (including your `A object;`), then the base classes (not present in your example).

As already said in a comment, you can easily step through the code in a debugger to get a better understanding of the order of execution.

Comment: I completely forgot that local object inside the builder works the same as in normal method. Once I exit from the builder all the local objects (stack objects) getting destroyed automatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because the object of class A is destroyed as soon the constructor of class B finishes (because it is a local variable inside a function) and it is before the class B destructor be called.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you've got your **object** (instance of Class A), *local* in your Constructor. When you now instantiate B in your main function, the constructor is called, creates **object**, and destroys it, as sonn as the constructor has finished.
In your first example, **object** is a class member and lives as long as your class object in your main function. When the programm is finished it calls your *costum* *Destructor*, this is then executed first, then it destructs all members (*standard Constructor*).